# xcopy python deployment

Tags: python, module, installation, virtualenv

I'm new to python and I'm writing my first program. I would like after I finish to be able to run the program from the source code on a windows or mac machine. My program has dependencies on 3rd party modules.

I read about virtualenv but I don't think it helps me because it says it's not relocatable and it's not cross-platform (see ***Making Environments Relocatable*** http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

The best scenario is to install the 3rd party modules locally in my project, aka xcopy installation.

I will be really surprised if python doesn't support this easily especially since it promotes simplicity and frictionless programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want, you just have to make sure that the directory containing your third-party modules is on the python path.

There's no requirement to install modules system-wide.

Comment: I guess that I can do that programatically from my script to include the current directory in the python path. In this case that's a good solution.

Comment: This works: i did sys.path.append('.') import <package> and it worked. one thing is that the packaged has to be unpacked from the tar.gz archive. I heard that python can handle the packages.tar.gz archive but i can't get it to work. any help?

Answer (score 1):

Note, while packaging your whole app with py2exe may not be an option, you can use it to make a simple launcher environment. You make a script with imports your module/package/whatever and launches the main() entry-point. Package this with py2exe but keep your application code outside this, as python code or an egg. I do something similar where I read a .pth text file to learn what paths to add to the sys.path in order to import my application code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, that's generally not how python works. Modules are installed site-wide and used that way. Are you familiar with pip and/or easy_install? Those + pypi let you automatically install dependencies no matter what you need.

If you want to create a standalone executable typically you'd use py2exe, py2app or something like that. Then you would have no dependencies on python at all.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work like this. Seeing how easy it is to create a package or anything, one can only wonder why you can't easily reference another module from your code without site wide installation.

converting the program to exe is not very good because i like the fact of modifying the program on the fly.

Comment: Relocatable and non-relocatable virtualenvs work too. But you're still installing packages the same way. They're just getting installed to something like `~/somenv/lib/python2.x/site-packages/` instead of `/usr/lib/python2.x/site-packages`.   Sure, with many packages you can manage the source code yourself and keep a local copy. But why? Python can handle that for you.

Comment: @chmullig.. relocatable doesn't work for windows so it's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I also found about [zc.buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) that can be used to include dependencies in an automatic way.